# Python recursive function to convert binary to decimal is working. I just don't understand how

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary, type-conversion, decimal

I will start this off by saying that I have not done any schooling. All of my programming knowledge has come from 12 years of doing various projects in which I had to write a program of some sort in some language.

That said. I am helping my friend who is just getting into programming and who is taking a introductory python class. Her class is currently learning about recursive functions. Due to my lack of schooling this is the first time I have heard about them. So when she asked me to explain why the function she had worked I couldn't do it. I had to learn them myself.

I have been looking around at various posts about solving this same problem. I found one here at [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-program-for-binary-to-decimal/) that is a function that does exactly what we need. With my elementary understanding of recursion this is the function that I would have thought would have been the right choice.

```py
def bintodec(n):
    if len(n) == 1:
        bin_digit= int(n)
        return bin_digit * 2**(len(n) - 1)
    else:
        bin_digit = int(n[0])
        return bintodec(n[1:]) + bin_digit * 2**(len(n) - 1)
```

This is the function she came up with

```py
def convertToDecimal(binNum):

    if len(binNum) == 0:
        return 0

    else:
        return convertToDecimal(binNum[:-1]) * 2 + int(binNum[-1])
```

When I print the function call it works.

```py
print(convertToDecimal("11111111"))
# results in 255

print(convertToDecimal("00000111"))
# results in 7
```

I understand that sometimes there is a shorthand way to things. I can't see any shorthand methods mentions in the documentation that I have read.

The thing that really confuses me is how it takes that string and does math with it. I see the typecast for int, but the other side doesn't have it.

This is where everything falls apart and my brain starts melting. I am thinking there is a core mechanic of recursion that I am missing. Normally that is the case.

So along to figuring out why that works, I would love to know how this method would compare to say the method we found over at [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-program-for-binary-to-decimal/)

Answer (score 2):

What your friend has implemented is the typical implementation of [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) for polynomial evaluation. Here is the formula.

[image]

Now think of the binary number as a polynomial with a's equal to one or zero, and x equals to 2.

Comment: Please do not add links without summarising their contents (the link to Wikipedia is fine because it mentions the method). The Internet is constantly changing and links often vanish into thin air. Could you please add the formula to your answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
The thing that really confuses me is how it takes that string and does math with it. I see the typecast for int, but the other side doesn't have it.
```

The "other side" will take the value as int number which is result of latest recursive function call. in this case it will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so in words, what this program is doing is, on each invocation, taking the string and splitting it into 2 parts, lets call them `a` and `b`. `a` contains the entire string, apart from the final character, while `b` only contains the final digit. 
Next, it takes `a` and calls the same function again, but this time with the shorter string, and then takes the result of this and doubles it. The doubling is done, as if you were to add an additional `0` to the end of a binary number, you would be doubling it.

Finally, it converts the value of `b` into an integer, either 1, or 0, and adds this to the previous result, which will be the decimal version of your binary string.

In other words, this function is only computing the result one character at a time, then it calls back to itself as a way of 'looping' to the next character.

It's important that there is an exit condition in a recursive function, to prevent infinite looping, in this case, when the string is empty, the program just returns 0, ending the loop.

Now on to the syntax. The only potentially confusing thing here I can see is python's array/slice syntax. Firstly, by trying to access the `-1` index in an array, you are actually accessing the final element.
Also in that snippet is slice notation, which is the colon `:` in the array index. This is essentially used to select a subset of an array, in this case, all elements but the final one.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly couldn’t make her function run as written.  I got the below error

> if len(binNum) == 0:
>   TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

I'm guessing however that under testing even working this would fail at some point, I’d like to see if you have it returning say, 221 (11011101) where the 1s and 0s are not consecutive and see if that works or fails.

Lastly, back to my error, I’m assuming the intention is to go out of the loop if it’s a zero.  Even if zero wasn’t a null character, `len(binNum) == 1` would still exit the loop as written.  A try/catch block would be better

Comment: Did you try calling it with a number?  It takes a string.